# Cannot Add Sections to Table View with Rx Swift and MVVM

Tags: mvvm, rx-swift

I 'm practicing SwiftRx with MVVM and TableView where i wrote down simple program to download data from remote api https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos .Now i want to group rows with data from api i-e  albumId but stuck in it.Please help me

i tried with seperate datasource but i am completely new and have not much understanding.

```
    viewModel.photoCells.bind(to: self.tableView.rx.items) {

        tableView, index, element in

        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: index, section: 0)
         switch element {

        case .normal(let viewModel):

            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "photoCell", for: indexPath) as? PhotosViewCell

                else {

                return UITableViewCell()
            }

            cell.viewModel = viewModel
            return cell
        case .error(let message):
            let cell = UITableViewCell()
            cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            cell.textLabel?.text = message
            return cell
        case .empty:
            let cell = UITableViewCell()
            cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            cell.textLabel?.text = "No data available"
            return cell
        }
        }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 0):

For this sort of work, your best bet is to use the [`RxDataSources`](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxDataSources) SDK. Read the documentation on it and find some tutorials too. If you have any more specific questions about it. Post them here or on the [RxSwift slack channel](http://slack.rxswift.org).